# Geometrical Interpretetion of Half Derivative

Tags: intuition, fractional-calculus

How would you understand in a intuitive way the meaning of:
$$D^{\frac{1}{2}}x^2=\frac{\Gamma(3)}{\Gamma(\frac{5}{2})}x^{\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{8}{3\sqrt{\pi}}x^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

or
$$D^{\frac{1}{2}}x=\frac{\Gamma(2)}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}x^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}x^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110241) and [this](http://www.maa.org/joma/volume7/podlubny/gifi.html).

Comment: @J.M. Thank you. I'm going to check it out.